# pig counting distinct leads to scalar has more than one row in output error

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a pig relation that reads some thing like -

```
describe A;
A:{header:(member_id, field_2,..)}
```

Now I want to tease out just the members so I do -

```
A1 = FOREACH A GENERATE A.header.member_id;
A2 = LIMIT A1 10;
dump A2;
```

This runs for a very long time culminating in the error - Unable to open iterator for alias A2. Backend error : Scalar has more than one row in the output.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is with the line:

```
 A1 = FOREACH A GENERATE A.header.member_id;
```

You shouldn't reference `A` in `A.header.member_id`.  Pig is doing operations over each tuple in `A` so it only sees the values in each tuple (in this case only `header`).  Since Pig doesn't see `A` in this scope it checks to see if it can use a relation (In your example `A`, `A1`, and `A2` are relations) instead.  However, it can only use that relation if it has one row; if it doesn't it creates the error you encountered.

The solution is just to change `A1` to:

```
 A1 = FOREACH A GENERATE header.member_id;
```